# Internal storage /emulated directory

Tags: samsung, internal-storage

I am trying to clear some internal storage i have in the emulated directory two identical folders one /0 and one /legacy both have exact same files can i delete one?

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: They don't *have* the same files; they *point* to the same files. I won't recommend deleting them.

Comment: They are the exact same file size

Comment: Well, create a file in `0`. Does it pop up in `legacy` as well?

Comment: Yeah it does added the pics above i created newnew in 0 and it showed in legacy

Answer (score 2):

Those are called "links", very common in Linux operating systems.

Chances are, your files are actually in neither of those directories. On my phone, the **actual** mountpoint of the partition those files are on is `/storage/sdcard0`.

From there two links exist. One to `/storage/emulated/legacy` and one to `/storage/emulated/0`. The `emulated` in the filename also suggests that both location are just, well, emulated.

This can vary from device to device, for example on an HTC I have here `/stoage/sdcard0` is just a link to `/storage/emulated/0` instead of the actual mountpoint.

**That said:** If you delete a file in one place, it's completely gone out of all two (or three) "places". The files have the same file sizes, but don't occupy twice the space on the partition. It is actually **the same file**. By that I mean it all points to the same place on the actual partition on your storage chip.

You can read more about links [here](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/linking-linux-filesystem).

Comment: Thanks thats what i was wanting to kno had it doubled up

Comment: Good explanation, answerer.

Comment: @lm2018 If I answered your question I'd appreciate you accepting my answer (little ✓ on the left of the answer).